# Why is a break forming between my twitter and facebook buttons?

Tags: css, twitter, facebook-like, positioning, twitter-follow

My website is up at  http://www.avidest.com/.  I have placed a facebook like button and a twitter follow button next to each other.  For some reason, the FB button is appearing below the twitter button as opposed to next to it.  I cannot figure out why.  I have placed a border around headertext to make it easier for you all to see it.  Here is my css:

```
.header {background:url(images/blackwhite10202.png); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center top; padding:0; margin:0 auto; width: 100%; }
.headertop{width: 100%;  background: transparent; height: 30px; min-width: 1020px;  padding-left: 50px; margin: 0 auto;}/*background: #d3e5e8;*/
.topholder1 { background: transparent; margin:0 auto; padding:0; }
.topholder1 .topholder2 { margin: 0 auto; width:1070px;  
.header_text { width:200px; float:right; font:normal 11px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; color:#9a9a9a; padding:6px 450px 10px 200px; margin:0; margin-right: 0px; border: 1px solid black;}
```

And here is the html:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="headertop">
  <div class="topholder1"> 
    <div class="topholder2">
        <img src="images/avidestlogo50perresave.png"  border="0" alt="logo" />
        <div class="header_text">

           Twitter button is here
           FB Button is here
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How do I make the two buttons appear side by side?  Thanks.

Comment: Your `.header_text` element has a width of only 200px set – yet you expect an element of 81px width and a second one with 450px to fit in there beside each other? Man, are you in for a surprise once you’ll start having Maths in school :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the width of `.header_text` is only 200px, but the fb widget is 450px wide.
and you have to add `float:left` to the twitter widget.